# Changing sidebar.php and footer.php depending on URL

Tags: theme-development, urls, sidebar, footer

I posed a similar question a few days back, but perhaps I put the question a bit incorrectly.

I would like my footer.php and sidebar.php to change depending on the URL. If URL contains /ru then show show ru-footer.php else show default footer (footer.php). The same should happen with the sidebar.

If it is possible, could you lead me step by step. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, this is how I did it and it works.

```
<?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (strpos($url, "/ru/"))  {
    $div_id = "logo_top_ru" .$contnet;
}else {
    $div_id = "logo_top_en" .$contnet;
}  
?>
<div id="<?php echo $div_id ?>"></div>
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If you will really use the URL as switcher then use the predefined variable of PHP `$_SERVER`. If you are new in the PHP world, use the function `var_dump( $_SERVER );` to understand, what is inside the variable on which key for your right solution. Also you can read the fine documentation about the variable: [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the `$pagename` variable...

```
$pos = strpos($pagename, "ru");
if ($pos !== false) {
     // ru specific content
} else {
     // default content
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated. I did it a bit differently though... I would write post it, but I cant since I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question. Still, thanks =)

Comment: I tried this out, but it didn't detect the difference between /ru/ and /en/... To clarify, even when I went to /en/ page it still showed the /ru/ content.